# Airflow 2 - ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.sensors'

Tags: airflow

After upgrading to Airflow 2, I got that error in some DAGs:

```py
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.sensors'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I resolved by change the import.

- old one

```py
from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator
```

- the new one that works

```py
from airflow.sensors import BaseSensorOperator
```

[BaseSensorOperator](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/base/index.html?highlight=basesensoroperator#airflow.sensors.base.BaseSensorOperator)

Comment: The ethical way was to remove your answer and give the green thick to my answer that works with current releases, instead of copying my answer inside yours. pity...

Answer (score 9):

I was trying to import `ExternalTaskSensor` and my research led me to this post, it turned out to be [this class](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/_api/airflow/sensors/external_task/index.html?highlight=externaltasksensor#airflow.sensors.external_task.ExternalTaskSensor).

The correct import for me was

```
from airflow.sensors.external_task import ExternalTaskSensor
```

Just FYI in case anyone runs into this in the future.

Answer (score 4):

The new one that works:

```
from airflow.sensors.base import BaseSensorOperator
```

***Chosen answer doesn't work for newer versions of Airflow.***

Comment: Could you be more precise? Please show which version of Airflow do you mean?

Comment: @AndrzejSydor First of all, thanks for your question and your answer as it helped me for more clearer vision. When I used your new library in my dag, i faced an error in my webserver that it couldn't be found, but i looked the BaseSensorOperator link online and figured it needs to mention "base" and just by adding this my problem was solved.

Comment: |Airflow ver 2.0.1

Comment: This is what your solution made my Airflow to look =====> 
    from airflow.operators.sensors import BaseSensorOperator
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'airflow.operators.sensors'

fixed when i follow my answer

Answer (score 2):

For Airflow 2.1.1 I first installed Amazon provider:

```
pip install apache-airflow-providers-amazon
```

and then imported **S3KeySensor**:

```
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3_key import S3KeySensor
```

Comment: Using Airflow 2.5.3, looks like the sensors have been moved. 
from airflow.providers.amazon.aws.sensors.s3 import S3KeySensor